# /var/lib/dpkg/status file as a repository for packages

Tags: apt

When I execute `apt-show-versions`, then I see few dozen packages with `No available version in archive` status. For example:

```
# apt-show-versions -a -p ffmpeg
ffmpeg:i386 6:0.8.17-1 install ok installed
No stable version
ffmpeg:i386 6:0.8.17-1 installed: No available version in archive
#
```

Common thing for all those packages is that they all have `/var/lib/dpkg/status` as an only available repository. For example:

```
# apt-cache policy ffmpeg
ffmpeg:
  Installed: 6:0.8.17-1
  Candidate: 6:0.8.17-1
  Version table:
 *** 6:0.8.17-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
#
```

Even packages with versions available in repository list `/var/lib/dpkg/status` as a repository with the lower priority:

```
# apt-cache policy tcpdump
tcpdump:
  Installed: 4.6.2-5+deb8u1
  Candidate: 4.6.2-5+deb8u1
  Version table:
 *** 4.6.2-5+deb8u1 0
        500 http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
#
```

Why is /var/lib/dpkg/status file listed as a repository for packages?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand well.  This is information, that a particular version is on your system.

for Example

```
$ LANG=C apt-cache policy k3b
k3b:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.0.2-8
  Version table:
     2.0.2-8 0
        500 http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
```

I have no k3b on my system, so nothing is in my status-file. They is no ffmpeg package available in your sources. I have backports and deb-multimedia.

```
     LANG=C apt-cache policy ffmpeg
ffmpeg:
  Installed: 10:2.6.9-dmo1
  Candidate: 10:2.6.9-dmo1
  Version table:
 *** 10:2.6.9-dmo1 0
        300 http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7:3.2-2~bpo8+2 0
        100 http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages



LANG=C  cat /var/lib/dpkg/status | egrep "Package: ffmpeg"-A9
Package: ffmpeg
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: graphics
Installed-Size: 1951
Maintainer: Christian Marillat <marillat@deb-multimedia.org>
Bugs: mailto:marillat@deb-multimedia.org
Architecture: amd64
Source: ffmpeg-dmo
Version: 10:2.6.9-dmo1
```

In the status file is your Version too.

apt-show-versions parses the dpkg status file and the files in /var/apt/lists. It seems you have upgradet from wheezy to jessie. And some packages from wheezy on your system.

I am not good explaining in english. I hope it was comprehensible

Comment: please use English on command output (easier to search) . (`OLD_LANG="$LANG", export LANG=C; <commands>... ;LANG="$OLD_LANG")`